# How to scrape recommendations on web page

Tags: python, scrapy

Consider this link :
https://www.michaelkors.com/logo-tape-ribbed-stretch-viscose-sweater/_/R-US_MH86NXK5ZW

Once you scroll down you see recommendations on this page. I want to get titles of these products mentioned. I have tried using this:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="product-tile-container"]/a/@src').getall()
```

However, it returns nothing. Reason might be that the products are lazy loaded. How should I extract their titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `selenium` to scroll to the bottom of the page. However, it still takes a while for the site to load the recommendations. As such, this solution waits by using a `while` loop until the product recommendation section appears:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import time
d = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/jamespetullo/Downloads/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.michaelkors.com/logo-tape-ribbed-stretch-viscose-sweater/_/R-US_MH86NXK5ZW')
last_height = d.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
   d.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
   time.sleep(0.5)
   new_height = d.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
   if new_height == last_height:
     break
   last_height = new_height

start = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser')
while start.find('div', {'class':'product-tile-rfk'}) is None:
   start = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser')

products = [i.find_all('li', {'class':'product-name-container'})[0].text for i in start.find_all('div', {'class':'product-tile-rfk'})]
```

Output:

```
['Ribbed Stretch-Viscose Tank', 'Ribbed Stretch-Viscose Tank Top', 'Ribbed Stretch-Viscose Tank Top', 'Stretch-Viscose Tank', 'Striped Ribbed Sweater Tank', 'Tie-Dye Stretch-Viscose Sweater', 'Striped Stretch-Viscose Tank', 'Striped Stretch-Cotton Sweater', 'Rainbow Stretch-Viscose Short-Sleeve Sweater', 'Stretch-Viscose Cropped Tank', 'Neon Striped Stretch-Viscose Tank Top', 'Geometric Grid Stretch-Viscose Top', 'Logo Tape Stretch-Viscose Pullover', 'Logo Tape Stretch-Viscose Cropped T-Shirt', 'Logo Tape Cotton-Jersey Top', 'Logo Tape Viscose Joggers', 'Logo Tape Buttoned Track Pants', 'Contrast Stripe Joggers', 'Contrast Stripe Hooded Jacket', 'Logo Tape Stretch-Viscose Pencil Skirt', 'Logo Tape Stretch-Viscose Zip-Up Hoodie', 'Stretch-Viscose Joggers', 'Cotton Asymmetric Turtleneck', 'Logo Tape Ribbed Knit Dress']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Python but your XPath cannot match. Try `//div[contains(@class, "product-tile-container")]//a//img/@src` instead. A single slash means that the element is a direct child of the previous one. A double slash means that you expect the mentioned element somewhere in the hierarchy of the current one.

You could make the XPath more robust if you add an additional path check for any `div` with the class `product-image-container`:  `//div[contains(@class, "product-tile-container")]//a/div[contains(@class, 'product-image-container')]//img/@src`

I highly suggest you to use an plugin to check XPath, e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl

Answer (score 0):

You can't access that data with a simple scrapy spider cause the page is rendered through **JS**. You can try by disabling the JS of your browser and refreshing the page. You will see a blank page. If you inspect it, you will notice there are no data related to the products.

If you want to scrape that type of JS rendered page, I would recommand you to use [splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) and [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash). It is well documented and easy to use. It is a rendering service that will allow you to scrape that data you want. (It is supported by scrapinghub, the smart brains behind scrapy).